# Get Object reference not set to an instance of an object error from static member

Tags: c#

I have a static class like this:

```
  public static class ApplicationList
    {
        public static List<ApplicationsModel> ApplicationsModels { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to use ApplicationsModels in another class

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetApplicationNameFromAppConfigAndAddToApplicationList();
        }

        private static void GetApplicationNameFromAppConfigAndAddToApplicationList()
        {
            List<string> applicationName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"].Split(',').ToList();

            foreach (var variable in applicationName)
            {
                ApplicationList.ApplicationsModels.Add(new ApplicationsModel { DateTime = DateTime.MinValue, Name = variable });

            }
        }
    }
```

But i my ApplicationList is null and get this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This is static Prpoerty and we can't create instance form static Prpoerty

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you have a

```
 public static List<ApplicationsModel> ApplicationsModels { get; set; }
```

property which is not initialized.

Can do something like this, instead:

```
public static class ApplicationList
{
    private static List<ApplicationsModel> appmodel = new List<ApplicationsModel>();
    public static List<ApplicationsModel> ApplicationsModels 
    { 
       get { return appmodel ;}
    }

    //DON'T THINK YOU NEED A SET IN THIS CASE.. 
    // BUT ADD IT, IF NEED
}
```

Comment: should static member initialize?

Comment: Sure. Static is *access* definition, but it remains a simple member like any other possible member, if you not initialize it, the default value for specified type will be applied. For List<T>, which is a *reference type* the default value is null.

Answer (score 2):

You get the null reference exception because the `List<ApplicationsModel> ApplicationsModels` is still null when you try to use it. Just declaring it as static doesn't means that the compiler or the framework adds for you the call to

```
ApplicationsModels = new List<ApplicationsModel>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, add this line before loading your list:

```
ApplicationsModels = new List<ApplicationsModel>();
```

**Longer answer:**

You need to initialise your `List` before you can add to it.

This is because a (reference-type) property will be `null` by default, and it wouldn't make sense to do `null.Add(item)`.

**Solution 1: Initialise before loading**:

The easy solution is to add an initialisation line before loading your list in your `Get...` method:

```
ApplicationsModels = new List<ApplicationsModel>();
```

However, this will reinitialise the list each time you call the `Get` method (which may or may not be what you want). You could place a check to only recreate the list if it is `null`, but if that's the behaviour you're after I'd lean towards one of the other solutions below.

**Solution 2: Use an initialised field instead of a property**:

Another way is to replace your property with an initialised field. Either:

```
public static List<ApplicationsModel> ApplicationsModels = new List<ApplicationsModel>();
```

Or:

```
public static List<ApplicationsModel> ApplicationsModels 
{ 
    get { return _applicationsModels; }
    set { _applicationModels = value; } // Do you really want a set?
}
private static List<ApplicationsModel> _applicationsModels = new List<ApplicationsModel>();
```

**Solution 3: Keep a property, but use a static constructor**:

Another way is to use a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in `ApplicationList`:

```
static ApplicationList()
{
    ApplicationsModels = new List<ApplicationsModel>();
}
```